# Parsing a json file to POJO using Jackson

Tags: java, json, twitter

I have a JSON file filled with twitter tweets such as the following:

```
{"text": "RT @7NewsSydney: Fire rips through party island Ibiza. #7News", "lang": "en", "coordinates": { "coordinates": [150.595679, -34.187708] , "type":"Point"}, "created_at": "Mon Mar 06 22:47:10 +0000 2017"}

{"text": "Fire rips through party island Ibiza. #7News ", "user": {"id": "156464691", "name": "7 News Sydney"}, "lang": "en","created_at": "Mon Mar 06 22:43:11 +0000 2017"}
```

I want to convert them into POJOs. The problem that I have is that the tweet is not the same. For example, the first tweet has a coordinate key-value where the second one doesn't.

I have defined the class Tweets as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

public class Tweets {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String text;
    private int coordinates;
    private String timestamp;
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Tweets tweets = mapper.readValue(new File(tweets.json), Tweets.class);
```

Is this parsing technique correct? Can someone help please.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if the file doesn't contain the tweet objects in an array that's not valid json and thus the mapper can't parse it - and it can't parse _two_ tweets into _one_ pojo. You probably want to either split your file (e.g. by line) or refactor it to contain a top level array and then parse it into a `Tweets[]`.

Comment: what do you mean by this "I'm pretty sure that if the file doesn't contain the tweet objects in an array that's not valid json and thus the mapper can't parse it" and yeah, I want to read it line by line, so how do i do that?

Comment: What I mean is that `{...} {...}` isn't valid json, it should be `[{..}, {...}]` instead. But if you want to read the file line by line it should be ok since you then only have one json object per line. You should look for how to read files line by line though. I'll give you a hint: `BufferedReader`.

Answer (score 0):

Coordinates should be defined differently (it is not an int but a composed object of an array of double and a string). 
If you want to parse multiple JSON objects defined in a file, you have to do it line by line since it is not a JSON array but a series of lines containing a JSON object per line. I would rename the class to Tweet and add the line-by-line parsed tweets in a list of Tweet.
If there aren't coordinates it is not a problem, they will be set to null if don't exist. If you don't eventually want to output them you can use the annotation @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) at the top of the class

Comment: So I want to parse the json line-by-line. So each tweet is a POJO object. So how would you do coordinates? and Im assuming that the for "ID" it is within an object of "user" which have two keys that are "ID" and "name" so how to tackle this?

Comment: For user, I would create another Jackson obect User whose properties are id and name (both String). Same for the coordinates, which will have properties coordinates (array of double) and type (String).